# Changing the order of routes in web.php file causes my application to throw a 404 error in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-9

I am trying to make CRUD (Create, Read, Update and Destroy) operations on Category class in my Laravel website. So, I have defined the relevant routes as below:

```
//Routes for Categories
Route::get('categories',[CategoryController::class, 'index'])->name('categories');
Route::get('categories/{category}',[CategoryController::class, 'show'])->name('show_category');
Route::get('categories/create',[CategoryController::class, 'create'])->name('create_category');
Route::get('categories/edit/{category}',[CategoryController::class, 'edit'])->name('edit_category');
Route::get('categories/destroy',[CategoryController::class, 'destroy'])->name('destroy_category');
Route::post('categories/store',[CategoryController::class, 'store'])->name('store_category');
Route::put('categories/update/{category}',[CategoryController::class, 'update'])->name('update_category');
```

Then I have made a view file named `create-category.blade.php` and finally, in the relevant controller for the Category model, I have written the following code for `create` method:

```
public function create()
{
    $pageTitle = "Create New Category";
    return view('create-category', compact('pageTitle'));
}
```

Using the codes mentioned above and the following line of code in my `categories.blade.php` file, I receive a 404 error when I try to access my `create-category.blade.php` file.

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('create_category') }}">Create New Category</a>
```

Having said all these, when I change the order of lines where my routes have been defined the problem gets solved. By this I mean when I change the `web.php` file like below, everything is OK (Basically, I move the create's routes to the first line).

```
//Routes for Categories
Route::get('categories/create',[CategoryController::class, 'create'])->name('create_category');
Route::get('categories',[CategoryController::class, 'index'])->name('categories');
Route::get('categories/{category}',[CategoryController::class, 'show'])->name('show_category');
Route::get('categories/edit/{category}',[CategoryController::class, 'edit'])->name('edit_category');
Route::get('categories/destroy',[CategoryController::class, 'destroy'])->name('destroy_category');
Route::post('categories/store',[CategoryController::class, 'store'])->name('store_category');
Route::put('categories/update/{category}',[CategoryController::class, 'update'])->name('update_category');
```

Is there any reasons behind this?

Comment: I suspect Laravel matches the requested URL against your routes from top to bottom to figure out which controller method to execute. If you request `categories/create`, it'll first try to match against `categories/{category}` and this matches if you replace `{category}` with `create`. This controller method probably throws the 404 because it can't find a category with the name `create`. If you change the order of the routes, it'll match against the `categories/create` route first and then it does work as expected.

Comment: @Marleen Thanks for your comment. So, what are is the purpose of using "{}" if it works like this?

Comment: I know Symfony allows you to specify constraints for the value in the `{}`, Laravel seems to have something similar: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints With that you could probably limit `{category}` to match (for example) digits only and keep the routes in your preferred order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Marleen says you have to set most exact routes first.
In your case it should look like

```
//Routes for Categories
Route::get('categories/edit/{category}',[CategoryController::class, 'edit'])->name('edit_category');
Route::put('categories/update/{category}',[CategoryController::class, 'update'])->name('update_category');
// ^ 3 segment routes are set first
Route::get('categories/create',[CategoryController::class, 'create'])->name('create_category');
Route::get('categories/destroy',[CategoryController::class, 'destroy'])->name('destroy_category');
Route::post('categories/store',[CategoryController::class, 'store'])->name('store_category');
// ^ 2 segment routes with exact match are set second
Route::get('categories/{category}',[CategoryController::class, 'show'])->name('show_category');
// ^ 2 segment routes with dynamic match is set third
Route::get('categories',[CategoryController::class, 'index'])->name('categories');
// ^ 1 segment route with exact match is set fourth
```

Answer (score 2):

For CRUD operations there is also a [Route::resource](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#restful-nested-resources), saves some lines and order issues

Answer (score 1):

My suggested code for you:

```
Route::resource('categories', CategoryController::class);
```

Comment: It would have been better to name the route as well

Comment: I am using different names from the default ones for my CRUD routes and that's why I think I cannot use this approach. But Thanks for offering.