# Add a dynamic route to laravel with lower priority than Fortify

Tags: laravel, routes

I want to add a route like this:

```
Route::get('/{teamslug}/{featureslug?}', [SomeController::class, 'show']);
```

The problem is that [Fortify](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/fortify) routes like '/login' no longer work with that route.
Is there an option to give the Forify routes a higher priority?

Comment: Set those first in the route file.

Comment: The Fortify routes are not declared in that route file. It is an external library.

Comment: You should check how it is loaded, those routes have to be loaded first. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71982763/changing-the-order-of-routes-in-web-php-file-causes-my-application-to-throw-a-40/71983416#71983416) what I mean.

Comment: Yes, but that is my question. I don't know how to do that. Here are the Fortify routes: https://github.com/laravel/fortify/blob/1.x/routes/routes.php

Comment: Try with putting `Fortify::ignoreRoutes();` in register method of FortifyServiceProvider. I am not sure if I am helping, just found something similar [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/proper-way-to-override-jetstreamfortify-auth-routes).

Comment: I found that same post, but than I would need to copy all those routes to my own route file. Doesn't seem like the best solution to me.

Comment: If you're not planning on modifying Fortify's default routes you could import them using `require_once(base_path('vendor/laravel/fortify/routes.php'))` inside your main web.php so you don't have to copy over anything. Not the cleanest solution but it works.